# Implementing mBaaS in Python

Tags: python, api, mobile, backend, mbaas

I am a web backend developer. In the past, I've used a lot of Python and specifically django to create custom APIs to serve data, in JSON for instance, to web frontends.

Now, I am facing the task of developing a mobile backend that needs to provides services such as push notifications, geolocating etc. I am aware of the existing mBaaS providers which could definitely address a lot of the issues with the task at hand, however, the project requires a lot of custom backend code, async tasks, algorithms to perform calculations on the data that in response trigger additional behavior, as well as an extensive back office.

Looking at the features of the popular mBaaS provider, I feel like they are not able to meet all my needs, however it would be nice to use **some** of their features such as push notifications, instead of developing my own. Am I completely mistaken about mBaaS providers? Is this sort of hybrid approach even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of options out there. Personally, I'm still looking for the holy grail of mBaaS providers. I've tried [Parse](http://parse.com), [DreamFactory](http://dreamfactory.com), and most recently [Azure Mobility Services](http://azure.com).

All three are great getting started from PoC to v1, but the devil is always in the details. There are a few details to watch out for:

1. You sacrifice control and for simplicity. Stay in the lanes and things should work. The moment you want to do something else is when complexity creeps in.
2. You are at the mercy of their infrastructure. Yes -- even Amazon and Azure go down from time to time. Note -- Dreamfactory is a self-hosted solution.
3. You are locked into their platform. Any extra code customizations
   you make with their hooks (ie - Parse's "CloudCode" and Azure's API
   scripts) will most likely not port to another platform.

Given the learning curve and tradeoffs involved I think you should just play the strong hand you already have. Why not host an Django app on Heroku? Add on DjangoRestFramework and you basically can get a mBaas up and running in less than a day.

Heroku has plenty of third party providers for things like Push notifications, Authentication mechanisms, and even search engines (Elasticsearch).

All that is required is to drop the right "pip install" code into your controllers and you are off an running.